# How to correctly show an image in portrait mode in html?

Tags: html, image, orientation, portrait

I'm using some simple photos on my website of which some are in landscape mode, and others in portrait mode. I use the most basic html possible:

```
<img src="/doc/54836abcc1a36b7526daa146">
```

When I visit the url (`/doc/54836abcc1a36b7526daa146`) directly in the browser I correctly see the image as standing/portrait mode, but when I use it in the html img-tag, it displays in landscape mode. Is this because I don't use an extension (like e.g.: `.jpg`). Or is something else wrong?

Does anybody know how I can correctly display the image in portrait mode? All tips are welcome!

Comment: when you visit the url, view page source on your page; anyhow you can use width *or* height in your tag for resize image and preserve ratio.

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS you can rotate or scale the image to view it in landscape or portrait. Here are examples:

Rotate the image 90 degrees:

```
img {
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Scale the image:

```
img {
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
}
```